# How to draw a line between 2 elements which are moving in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Not sure if this is possible, but I'm looking for a way to draw a line between 2 moving(animated) elements. I know that you cant set a position this way with CSS, but I know that you can skew a line, but this is done with % so you cant set a position here.

I have included a working fiddle. Also, the animations are laggy and need to be more natural if that is possible.

```
// HTML

<div id="dotcontainer">

    <div id="dot-1" class="dots">
        <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="dot-2" class="dots">
        <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="dot-3" class="dots">
        <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>

</div>

// JS

$(document).ready(function() {

    animateDiv( $('#dot-1 .dot') );
    animateDiv( $('#dot-2 .dot') );
    animateDiv( $('#dot-3 .dot') );

});

function makeNewPosition($container) {

   // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    $container = ($container || $(window))
    var h = $container.height() - 10;//10 is dot size
    var w = $container.width() - 10;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh, nw];

}

function animateDiv($tar) {

    var $target = $tar;
    var newq = makeNewPosition($target.parent());
    var oldq = $target.offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    //var speed = 1000;

    $tar.animate({
        top: newq[0],
        left: newq[1]
    }, speed, function() {
        animateDiv($(this));
    });

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

    return speed;

}

// CSS

#dotcontainer{

    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #eee;

}

.dots{

    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;

}

.dot{

    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}        

#dot-1{

    top: 60px;
    left: 100px;

}

#dot-2{

    top: 100px;
    left: 290px;

} 

#dot-3{

    top: 230px;
    left: 250px;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/at8smy5f/

Comment: oooppss, thanks....added!

Comment: A line going from `#dot-1` to `#dot-2` for example, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, from dot 1 to dot 2. And from dot 2 to dot 3 and so on.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/daveboling/pen/jWOorz)?

Comment: Thanks this is usefull, well I can draw a line to each dot, but they wont move when the dot moves...